# How can I install Ubuntu from within Windows XP on an old PC with no CD reader nor USB port?

Tags: system-installation, windows-xp

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 and 13.10 but somewhy I always find a problem on my way. I have no CD reader and I can't find the way to make my PC recognize the USB ports as "bootable" ports. Has anyone done this before? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you mount the iso virtually with Daemon Tools or PowerISO and run it, you should get a screen with an option of *"Demo Installation."* Try that it should get you to Live Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried your BIOS setup?  Also, sometimes the USB is listed under a sub-category of hard disk on the boot choice/device menu.  Phoenix and Nvidia  comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be the boot order of the BIOS.
When the computer is booting, press F2 (or F12 or F8, depending on the maker).
That should open the BIOS menu. Select "boot" or "boot order" and set USB as first booting device.
Save&Exit (normally F10 key) and now you should be able to boot from USB.

If you still can't boot, verify that your USB drive is working. Maybe test it on a different machine.

If nothing works, then the only option would be to take out the HDD and connect it on a machine with working USB ports and/or CD drive.

I hope it helps. Good luck

Edit - if your computer is very old, you may want to install a light version of Ubuntu, like lubuntu or kubuntu.